# Authors on the Philosophy of Ancient Egypt

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy

What philosophies or systems of believes apart from the religious ones did those people have? Were there any forums in which ideas were discussed? Were there any significant philosophers or high intellectuals during this period of time? What were the main ideas during that time?

**I'm looking for authors and books on this matter**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, you are out of luck. [Wikipedia's Ancient Egyptian Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_philosophy) begins with "*Almost nothing is known of Ancient Egyptian philosophy*". It does mention a name and gives some references. Also, does "this matter" refer to the paragraph above or the picture below? If it is the latter (and in any case) you may want to tell where you got it from and what it is supposed to be.

Comment: @Conifold I checked with wikipedia before asking. My hope is that perhaps some university professor or author stumbled into "something". thanks anyway

Comment: NO; no extant records about "philosophy".

Comment: You can see Henri Frankfort, et al., [Before Philosophy: The Intellectual Adventure of Ancient Man](https://archive.org/details/FrankfortEtAl.1964BeforePhilosophy).

Comment: The Corpus Hermeticum is a late text but well worth a read.

Comment: Ancients did not make the distinction that has arisen in the West (and I would venture to say only since the Renaissance) as to philosophy and religion - more properly - theology. They were intertwined. They still are in the East.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to wikipedia there are no records on Ancient Egyptian Philosophy apart from:

[Ptahhotep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptahhotep) Who according to this source he's arguably a philosopher. There is a book on his reflections on Ethis and daily conduct by:

**Browder, Anthony (1988). Nile Valley Contributions to Civilization. Karmaic Institute.**

[Source here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_philosophy)

Related:

**Henri Frankfort, et al. Before Philosophy: The Intellectual Adventure of Ancient Man. [Reference here](https://archive.org/details/FrankfortEtAl.1964BeforePhilosophy)**

Comment: They also mention Asante's book, but what is the point of mirroring Wikipedia here? Lefkowitz has a [paper on Egyptian influence on Greeks](https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/egyptian-philosophy-influence-on-ancient-greek-thought/v-1) (mostly made up).

Comment: @Conifold it's sometimes valid in these networks to make searches easier. Besides I'm adding new references not in wikipedia. If it's not the case here I'll delete it.

Comment: What came from Egypt is an interesting question. In what sense was philosophy a kind of religious commitment?  (P. Hadot: maniere de vivre). It seems certain there was Egyptian influence on the Greeks, but teasing out any direct influence is difficult.  http://www.math.tamu.edu/~dallen/history/pythag/pythag.html

Comment: There was a "religious flavor" maybe this is the wrong word. P. Hadot.https://www.iep.utm.edu/hadot/  Did this originate in Egypt?  Maybe the specialists know more in this area.